# Java String.contains() not working properly

Tags: java, string, list, contains

I am implementing a search in my app with hashtags. The idea is that the program will loop all existing posts in my databse and check if the is all the input hashtags in the currentPost and then it will add the post to the recyclerView

For some reason the string.contains is not working properly, for example I searched "brasil historia" and there are both hashtags, but the function return as false

This is the method I'm using:

```
private boolean checkTagsSearch(List<String> tags, String searchString, String query) {

        String[] searchHashtagsList = query.split(" ");
        int numberOfSearchedTags = searchHashtagsList.length;
        int counter=0;
        // if there is the search string in the tags
        // se o post tiver a search string
        for(String currentTag : tags){
            Log.i("checkTags", "search: " + searchString + " currentTag: " + currentTag+ " counter: "+counter);
            Log.i("checkTags", "search string contains? " + searchString.contains(currentTag));

            if (searchString.contains(currentTag)) {
                counter++;

                if(counter == numberOfSearchedTags) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;

    }
```

Here is the Log I got for the Log.i:

As you can see in here the search string was "brasilhistoria" and it searched through brasil and historia, but the contains is false

```
2021-02-07 08:28:18.115 22455-22455/com.I/checkTags: search: brasilhistoria currentTag: brasil  counter: 0
2021-02-07 08:28:18.115 22455-22455/com.I/checkTags: search string contaiins? false
2021-02-07 08:28:18.115 22455-22455/com.I/checkTags: search: brasilhistoria currentTag: imperio  counter: 0
2021-02-07 08:28:18.115 22455-22455/com.I/checkTags: search string contaiins? false
2021-02-07 08:28:18.116 22455-22455/com.I/checkTags: search: brasilhistoria currentTag: primeiroreinado  counter: 0
2021-02-07 08:28:18.116 22455-22455/com.I/checkTags: search string contaiins? false
2021-02-07 08:28:18.116 22455-22455/com.I/checkTags: search: brasilhistoria currentTag: historia  counter: 0
2021-02-07 08:28:18.116 22455-22455/com.I/checkTags: search string contaiins? false
```

Comment: Your tags appear to contain spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are trailing whitespaces in your tags. See the double whitespace between `brasil` and `counter` in `search: brasilhistoria currentTag: brasil  counter: 0`! That means the `currentTag` in that case was not `brasil` but `brasil`  and `brasil`  is not contained in `brasilhistoria`.

Solution: `trim` the tags at some point to remove the trailing whitespaces.

Comment: Hi! this space is actually from the log. I erased the space from the log like this:  
 `Log.i("checkTags", "search: " + searchString + " currentTag:" + currentTag); ` and now it shows like this: `I/checkTags: search: slides currentTag:slides 
I/checkTags: search string contaiins? false `
 So this can't really be the problem. Any ideas of what else it might be?

Comment: @Nina No, there are two whitespaces, one is from the log statement, the other is from the `currentTag`. You can e.g. log the length of the tag to see that, or encapsulate it in `'` to see the actual boundaries of the `currentTag`. In your latest log statement the trailing whitespace is "hidden" by the fact that the line ends there and therefore you do not visibly see the whitespace as before.

Comment: Hi! There really was a space! I could only see it with the lenght! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have space after your `currentTag` and then you invoke e.g:

```
"brasilhistoria".contains("brasil ");
```

answer is false